# Conditional unique constraint with multiple fields in oracle db

Tags: sql, oracle, conditional-statements, unique, unique-constraint

I have this table:

```
XPTO_TABLE (id, obj_x, date_x, type_x, status_x)
```

I wanna create a unique constraint that applies to the fields `(obj_x, date_x, type_x)` only when `status_x <> 5`.

I have tried to create this one but Oracle says:

```
line 1: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UN_OBJ_DT_TYPE_STATUS
ON XPTO_TABLE(
    (CASE
         WHEN STATUS_X <> 5
         THEN
             (OBJ_X,
              TO_CHAR (DATE_X, 'dd/MM/yyyy'),
              TYPE_X)
         ELSE
             NULL
     END));
```

What's the correct syntax ?

Comment: I think you need to make it a check constraint and not a unique index.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck I though that also, but He has to say what values He wanna check. Doesn't make sense a constraint that has no value to check on that 3 fields. And doesn't make sense either to be an index with such a constraint (even if it was possible)

Comment: @jamesfrj I think you should explain better what you need. Because as I said on previous comment does not make any sense what your are trying to do. So put some data sample and what should be constrained if you try to insert some data (I'm saying constraint because of your question.)

Comment: Guys, I've found a way using a function that concatenates the values of the fields and then returns a sole result. Then I can create the index like: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UN_OBJ_DT_TYPE_STATUS
    ON XPTO_TABLE (
    SUBSTR (FUN_UNIQUE_XPTO (OBJ_X, TYPE_X, DATE_X, CROB_IN_STATUS),
                1,                20))

Comment: I took my solution based on http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1249800833250  I think there is better explained

Answer (score 28, accepted):

@jamesfrj: it looks like you are trying to ensure that your table should contain only one record for which `status <>5`.

You can try creating a unique functional index by concatenating the columns, as given below

```
      create table XPTO_TABLE (id number, 
                            obj_x varchar2(20),
                            date_x date,
                            type_x varchar2(20),
                            status_x varchar2(20)                              
                           );

      create unique index xpto_table_idx1 on XPTO_TABLE(case when status_x <>'5'  THEN              obj_x||date_x||type_x||STATUS_x ELSE null END);
```

Comment: This s too restrictive - it may forbid some rows even if they are not real duplicates.

Comment: @Vishad, that is the perfect solution for my case.  I had created a function before, but your way is much more cleaner.  I am using it now.  Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I want to add a unique constraint to an existing table bat it gets an error

ALTER TABLE T_EVENTATTENDEE ADD CONSTRAINT EVENT_ATTENDEE_UNIQUE UNIQUE (CASE WHEN C_DELETED = 0 THEN ( F_USER, F_EVENT ) ELSE null END);

ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Answer (score 8):

Under Oracle 11, you can create a bunch of virtual columns that get non-NULL value only when   STATUS_X is 5, and then make *them* unique:

```
CREATE TABLE XPTO_TABLE (
  ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  OBJ_X INT,
  DATE_X DATE,
  TYPE_X VARCHAR2(50),
  STATUS_X INT,
  OBJ_U AS (CASE STATUS_X WHEN 5 THEN OBJ_X ELSE NULL END),
  DATE_U AS (CASE STATUS_X WHEN 5 THEN DATE_X ELSE NULL END),
  TYPE_U AS (CASE STATUS_X WHEN 5 THEN TYPE_X ELSE NULL END),
  UNIQUE (OBJ_U, DATE_U, TYPE_U)
);
```

You can freely insert duplicates, as long as STATUS_X is **not** 5:

```
INSERT INTO XPTO_TABLE (ID, OBJ_X, DATE_X, TYPE_X, STATUS_X) VALUES (1, 1, '1-JAN-2014', 'foo', 4);
INSERT INTO XPTO_TABLE (ID, OBJ_X, DATE_X, TYPE_X, STATUS_X) VALUES (2, 1, '1-JAN-2014', 'foo', 4);
```

But trying to insert a duplicate when STATUS_X is 5 fails:

```
INSERT INTO XPTO_TABLE (ID, OBJ_X, DATE_X, TYPE_X, STATUS_X) VALUES (3, 1, '1-JAN-2014', 'foo', 5);
INSERT INTO XPTO_TABLE (ID, OBJ_X, DATE_X, TYPE_X, STATUS_X) VALUES (4, 1, '1-JAN-2014', 'foo', 5);

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (IFSAPP.SYS_C00139498) violated
00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
           For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
           this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
*Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the CREATE UNIQUE INDEX is expecting only a value you can concatenate the columns as follow

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UN_OBJ_DT_TYPE_STATUS
ON XPTO_TABLE(
(CASE
     WHEN STATUS_X <> 5
         THEN OBJ_X || TO_CHAR (DATE_X, 'dd/MM/yyyy') || TYPE_X
     ELSE
         NULL
 END));
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UN_MYID_uniq_IDX
ON MYTABLE(
(CASE
     WHEN MY_id > 1428923
         THEN MY_INDEX_COLUMN
     ELSE
         NULL
 END));
```

`MY_INDEX_COLUMN` value cannot be repeated if `my_id` is greater than `1428923`.