# Can I add a unique constraint to a partition?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I failed to find an explicit answer on the topic and didn't pick it up from the documentation.

I want to partition a table by status (A and B), could I add a unique constraint that would apply only to partition A?

Meaning that while a record is with status A it must be unique but if I update it to status B then it would no longer apply to it?

Comment: There is [Partial Indexes](http://richardfoote.wordpress.com/2013/07/08/12c-partial-indexes-for-partitioned-tables-part-i-ignoreland/) in 12c. Seems that uniqueness can be enforced with help of partial local unique index, have to verify though. Of course it is not good practice to enforce uniqueness with index instead of constraint but at least it is better then nothing.

Comment: See also AskTom [Local unique indexes on partitioned tables](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:9536970000346702362) where he explains why local index uniqueness is not allowed without partitioning prefix.
More on the same topic: https://richardfoote.wordpress.com/2007/12/20/local-index-issue-with-partitioned-pk-and-unique-key-constraints/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fistly, if you are planning to update the partitioning Key in a table, hope you have

> "Enable Row Movement" enabled

Secondly, don't think it can be done directly using a normal BTree index. You will need to use a Functional Index, Virtual Column as given in : [Conditional unique constraint with multiple fields in oracle db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21088601/conditional-unique-constraint-with-multiple-fields-in-oracle-db/21089804#21089804)