# UNIQUE constraint combining multiple columns with a condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table in Oracle 11g such as with below columns.

- COL1_STATUS
- COL2_ID
- COL3_TYPE
- COL4_DATE

I want to create a UNIQUE constraint combining all 4 columns but only when COL1_STATUS = 10

How can I do that? Table is already created so I am looking for only ALTER command.

Also, I have searched and found similar question where it is suggested to use unique index but I want to achieve this by constraint.

[Conditional unique constraint with multiple fields in oracle db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21088601/conditional-unique-constraint-with-multiple-fields-in-oracle-db)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A unique index and a constraint are essentially the same thing.  A unique constraint is implement using a unique index.  So this really should do what you want:

```
create unique index idx_table_4 on
    table(case when status = 10 then id end,
          case when status = 10 then type end,
          case when status = 10 then date end);
```

In fact, this is how the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm) recommends implementing a unique constraint:

> When you specify a unique constraint on one or more columns, Oracle
>   implicitly creates an index on the unique key. If you are defining
>   uniqueness for purposes of query performance, then Oracle recommends
>   that you instead create the unique index explicitly using a CREATE
>   UNIQUE INDEX statement. You can also use the CREATE UNIQUE INDEX
>   statement to create a unique function-based index that defines a
>   conditional unique constraint. See "Using a Function-based Index to
>   Define Conditional Uniqueness: Example" for more information.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you.